# What's up with the new CSS?

Tags: support, user-interface, design

I've just noticed the new rep/vote counts look different, and not in a good way (IMO, obviously people will disagree).

[image]

What else has been changed, and is it permanent?

Comment: Yeah, I've saw it rolled out on meta first. And now on SO. I wonder why the change?

Comment: If Facebook has taught us anything, it's that changes to the layout/format of any site is BAD!!!!!!

Comment: I sort of liked the clunky, curmudgeonly old **bold fonts** on SO. Leave the nice sleek interfaces to the new wesites on SE.

Comment: Eeek! Your post is [missing something](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83625/172936)...

Comment: But +1 for the free-hand circles. And arrows.

Comment: Just when I was about to make a question myself! :)

Comment: The vote arrows look so fat.

Comment: That's not nice, @Ben - they're just retaining rep.

Comment: @Shog9 They are latitudinally gifted.

Comment: @Shog9 They're probably retaining their own zipcode at this point

Comment: Thought it was my browser going crazy, especially since I'm having issues at P.SE http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5180/51669

Comment: @asa - you were 100% correct to put a screen shot. Once they change their minds this post will serve as evidence - a living history of... a bunch of [neophobiacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neophobia)...

Comment: With the holiday season quickly approaching it was time for SO to go on a bit of a diet.  There's a little less to <3 now but we'll make up for it - promise!

Comment: Bring back the **bold**! (At least for rep)

Comment: I'm offering a bounty (here) for [the script](http://stackapps.com/?as=1) that will get it back to **bold**.

Comment: The font family is the same. The new size is 24px, the old size was... 200% - and of course the weight went from bold to normal.

Comment: I like it. Looks sharper.

Comment: @TLama: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158770/178438 Done :)

Comment: @Asad: Ah, I was talking about the post score. Haven't really paid attention to what, exactly, changed in the half-dozen other places where things changed.

Comment: @Manishearth, brilliant! Thanks! Bounty will arrive in few days... To the others, have a nice discussion :-)

Comment: Now - if we could remove the rest of the pointless bold and also stop using Arial for Helvetica, we could *begin* to have a typographically consistent site :-) Thanks Jin

Comment: Wait, you're not Panama...

Comment: @MichaelMrozek What do you mean?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I less than three you.

Comment: Bring back the fat! Fat = healthy

Comment: Anybody can make their own CSS to override the css on websites. All major browsers support that.

Comment: New style is extremely ugly. The only reason I don't participate in some stackexchange sites (like CodeReview) is the ugly design. Now I hate this SO unreadable fonts.

Comment: You look different tonight, Stack Overflow. Have you been working out?

Comment: It would be more useful to make changes that meant images didn't look like crap on a retina display.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek :-P what did I do now?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA This seemed like the kind of question you'd post. Ridiculously it's up to +80 now; if you'd posted it it'd probably have been closed

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I know... wth

Comment: So ... was there any reason for this change?  Was the SO team bored?  Did the CEO visit the devs, who then needed to look busy?  Did somebody lose a bet?  Seriously, either way is fine, but why change?

Comment: @MattFenwick The old interface was cluttered and a member of the team redesigned it. I don't like some aspects, but I'm pretty sure on the whole it is an improvement.

Comment: @Asad - probably true, but I hope the team will at least bring back the nicer bold text for question/answer scores and rep, at the very least.

Comment: @AdamRackis And direct their attention to truly godawful looking pages like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers)

Comment: @Asad - DUDE - they're messing around with good, popular styles while abominations like that exist?!  smh

Comment: I’m voting to close because any questions about the aesthetic changes that took place nine years ago is pretty much obsolete.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Userscript alert!

[Bring back the Bold!](https://stackapps.com/questions/3830/bring-back-the-bold)

This script nourishes them numbers back to good health.

Comment: Yeah I was fiddling with it, but 110% for font-weight didn't seem *quite* right.

Comment: @Asad: Yeah, I looked it up on sites where it _hadn't_ changed. StackApps itself still has the normal style.

Answer (score 82):

I agree. Compare the healthy

[image]

[image]

to the poor undernourished

[image]

[image]

I want the old style back.

Comment: The score text should get fatter as it goes up and thinner as it passes zero...

Comment: Interestingly, a bug on several sites *was* actually causing posts scores to get bigger as they passed 100. This wasn't intentional though (they're supposed to get smaller at 3 digits).

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the vote count netting a full 64 votes _lower_ after the change... Eeeeek!

Comment: @sehe Not only that, the question text became a lot shorter too.

Comment: Maybe the vote count isn't undernourished, but the arrows are obese?

Answer (score 45):

The old design was nice, but those heavy, bold numbers added unnecessary weight. With over 280,438,789 views a month on Stack Overflow, that weight was no longer acceptable, particularly considering we're still running off of backup hardware in Oregon. Fortunately, our brave designer-in-chief was able to find numerous small ways to slim down the text without sacrificing clarity.

The new font styles trim the fat, allowing emphasis where it's needed without bogging down the pipes pushing all those extra pixels.

Next time you load up Stack Overflow and the page appears in 70ms, be sure to whisper a quick, "thanks, Jin!"

Comment: Okay, so it's like April Fools with extra Christmas, right? *Right?*

Comment: While I generally agree that the 'unbolding' is a good thing, I'm not sure I truly appreciate the unbolding of the vote number on posts.

Comment: Wait, so making things bold was a performance issue?

Comment: ☛ *Thinneeeer...*

Comment: I honestly think the unbolded numbers look much more professional...

Comment: @Mysticial He said something about them being heavy and adding weight. I never knew you had to pay for bandwidth by the kilogram.

Comment: Well, I don't like it now, but I have a feeling I'll either grow to appreciate it or not care after a couple weeks. As far as the pushing pixels argument is concerned, that's cray.

Comment: Shenanigans.  The size of the font doesn't matter (we users take the pixel-moving hit), unless you're saying the extra `font-weight:bold` text in the CSS was clogging your servers.  Really?  Oh, wait.  ***It's Friday.*** (slowing down your servers with a bit of bold/italic.  You're welcome)

Comment: Joking, @Asad? I'm shocked that you would think that - SHOCKED! Per the conservation of energy principle, energy lost to the extra white pixels now on your screen are complemented by that saved during transmission - so for a trivial cost in battery life on your end, we save *millions* in transmission costs!

Comment: I personally think it looks like... not good.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [You don't say](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/210/119/+_2acc5a8841f8752904d37f90a8014829.png)?

Comment: I'm sorry, but "professional" should not trump readability. The new font is universally *smaller*, and harder to read.

Comment: Anyways, I think I've found the solution. We can just revert the font, and close chat.SO down instead. This will likely save more network traffic, while having the added benefit of doubling the effective answering capacity on SO

Comment: @Tim: If you're having trouble reading that text, you might want to get your eyes checked. The score is still a much larger font than the rest of the text on the page. If you can't read the score, how are you reading everything else on the page? I actually think the text is *easier* to read without the bold. It goes both ways.

Comment: @animuson You're right, but readability isn't *just* about whether you can see something clearly. It's also about how much attention something grabs (although it could be argued excessive attention towards the vote totals is undesirable).

Comment: @Asad you just answered why the changes were made. When everything is made important on a page, then nothing is. Sure, it may take some time to get used to if you're a regular user but I believe the changes are for the better.

Comment: @Jin Btw I really like [all the other changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158777/200500). Thanks!

Comment: @Asad thank you! I'm very conscious about making visual tweaks to a high traffic site such as SO. There's this perpetual struggle everyone wanting something new and fresh, but still wants to keep the familiarity. I've gotten a lot of requests to "redesign" SO. I won't redesign SO, but my goal is simply to tidy up the site a bit. Instead of a major release of changes at once, I prefer to do small incremental ones so it's less of an impact. Give the new changes some time to sink in. I bet you won't even notice after a few days.

Comment: Does this diamond make me look fat?

Comment: @Jin While you're at it, is there any chance of toning down the page headings as well? They seem much too bold in comparison to the rest now.

Comment: When you move your hardware from Oregon to somewhere else, please bring the old font back...

Answer (score 42):

The new style **objectively** sucks! ☺ I can tell from some of the pixels and from seeing quite a few voting widgets in my time.

The thinner font makes the vote counts look off-center. Example (colored lines added to demonstrate the pixels are off-center):

- The digits are too far to the right:
  [image: 13] [image: 12]
- The digits are too far to the right, and too low:
  [image: 6]

While the bold style probably wasn't perfectly centered either, this is the first thing I noticed with the new style.

(This is with Firefox 17 on Linux.)

Comment: That's inevitable when you move the cheese, you need at least one pixel.

Comment: FWIF I like the new style. But you’re right about the lack of centeredness of everything that contains a 1. Blame the lack of proportional font support by browsers.

Comment: It's actually the arrows that are offset to the left by 1 pixel, due to putting a 26px-wide arrow inside a 41px-wide box. The text is perfectly centered. The arrows are just, eh... a mess...

Comment: Our new Director of the CIA, everyone.

Answer (score 29):

***Pffft.***

Every time Facebook makes a little change to their page, they have to endure the weight of hundreds of thousands of emails from disgruntled users crashing their servers.

You'd be kerfluffled no matter what the change was.  Give it a few days to get accustomed to the new look, and *then* file a bug report.

Comment: But I'm angry NOW

Comment: But unlike ****book, here they actually reply...

Comment: DISLIKE!!!!!!!!!! (extra !'s to get past char limit)

Comment: Change bad! Hulk SMASH!

Comment: I checked the site on my iPad and thought "this (the vote controls) looks awful" but figured it was maybe an issue with how the ipad was rendering it. It doesn't look *as* bad on my main computer but it doesn't look right either. There's a few changes made as part of this 'revision' of the site layout that make sense, but I truly think the vote layout change is a mistake. Getting used to something that's wrong might stop the complaints but it doesn't correct the problem.

Comment: It's been a few days. It still sucks.

Comment: I agree, bring back the bold vote counts!

Comment: Proof: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270461/please-unbold-the-reputation-next-to-a-users-card

Answer (score 29):

## Attention bold lovers

It is now clear that Stack Overflow is no longer the place for you. **Fear not**, [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions) will always welcome your **bold awesomeness**.

[image]

<sub>Just no "what language I should learn next" questions, mmmkay?</sub>

Comment: Which font is the best *as a programmer?*

Comment: @Shog9 Whiteboard Regular

Answer (score 25):

> What else has been changed?

A few other places that I noticed:

- Question lists:

  [image: question list]

  [image: question list 2]
- Inside a post:

  [image: post view]
- In profile, tag lists:

  [image: tags]
- In profile, account list:

  [image: accounts]
- Question list top tabs:

  [image: question list tabs]
- Inside post tags (tagged):

  [image: tagged]

---

IMO: looks cool, minimalistic, *sophisticated*. And as Yoda says, deal with it.

Comment: Anyone has a diff please? I already hardly remember what it looked like before…

Comment: Just look for screenshots on the Internet. They changed the vote count, answer count, reputation score, number of questions tagged, tabs, relative time - remove bold or reduce size or both. Removing bold for reputation score of user in question/answer is an OK decision, but the rest just make it harder to see (for me at least).

Comment: @poke i guess that means that you are already used to the new style, we are programmers, our brains adapt fast :) I don't have a diff btw. You might want to search for screenshots as nhahtdh suggests.

Answer (score 15):

Dropping emphasis and styles made the site harder to read. Drawing the eye's attention to the highlighted parts of the page is important. Having to scan longer with the eye makes more strain.

There are millions of users here all who probably get enough eye strain as it is. Why add to it? I will take my load time of 71ms and some nice styles instead of 70ms and eye strain.

Comment: Scan harder for what? After a few days of using the site, you should know where the vote count is at. You shouldn't need to "scan" for it.

Answer (score 8):

If we are sticking with the non-bold counts, can we consider less bold up and down arrows? :-(

Answer (score 6):

Do these new rules need to be `!important`? Certainly it looks like the font-weight on the "answered" rep score works fine without it.

[image: New CSS from IE8 Developer Tools]

Comment: The draconian CSS nazis want to make sure no one beats the system by [using an alternative style sheet](http://userstyles.org/stylish/).

Comment: Well, we can just override the rule with another `!important`.

Answer (score 5):

I almost didn't notice the changes in the layout.

I just wondered why so many posts were made community-wiki, until I noticed that I was wrong. If I remember correctly, the old design had some grey boxes surrounding the user info underneath each post, only posts marked as community-wiki had not. The new design omits these boxes, giving the first impression that each answer (questions still have the box) is a community-wiki one. The community-wiki answers had no user image showing, but still this confuses me...

Answer (score 5):

The new font style is fine to me.

However, other things which were previously very well balanced with the old font style are now completely out of balance. On top 1 the vote arrows. They are now *clearly* disproportional. The fix should be relatively easy: make them smaller and very maybe put a 1x wide bright shadow on it to be in balance with the new font style.

Further it is also distracting that the new font style didn't made it into [Top Users list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers), [Answers tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc?tab=answers) nor [Tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc?tab=tags). It's still the old and fat font style.

Answer (score 2):

While it was extremely annoying at first, now I've gotten really used to it. I think everyone has. In fact, I've gotten *so* used to it that the styling on StackApps looks *fat* to me and burns my eyes:
[image]

For reference, StackApps and MSO had the same styling before the CSS revamp, and StackApps still has the old CSS.