# Can we somehow bring the old score font back?

Tags: feature-request, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s up with the new CSS?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158762/whats-up-with-the-new-css)

I woke up today, got a shower and headed to my daily morning stacktivities. I opened the page, and noticed, to my horror, that there's something terribly, infinitely wrong with the font used to score answers and questions. At first I thought it's only my local problem, but quick visit to `Lounge` confirmed my worst thoughts.

So, is there any way to bring the old font back? I tend to use SO on iPad a lot (the normal webpage version), and I think new font is sligthly less readable. And of course, I was used to the old font.

I believe I'm not the only one that misses the old font.

Comment: [Bring back the Bold!](http://stackapps.com/q/3830/11265)

Comment: See also: [How to change all fonts on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300905/309993)