# Tiny layout bug: vote count

Tags: bug, voting, design

On a question page the vote count is slightly offset to the right. This is very much nitpicking of me but it drives me crazy. I have OCD. So I'm reporting it.

[image]

(I drew alignment markers to make sure I'm not crazy.)

Comment: It was brought up in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158793/179419) but I guess not fixed...

Comment: This is almost as bad as Apple's iOS division refusing to fix the optically off-center date in their calendar app icon. =D

Answer (score 6):

I've stated this elsewhere before, but this is actually caused by the voting arrows. The arrows themselves are only 26 pixels wide (or 40 pixels wide in the "on" state), but they're being placed in a container that's 41 pixels wide. As you can imagine, you can't center an even number inside an odd number on the web (half pixels don't exist, so it gets rounded either way).

The text representing the vote score is perfectly centered and can't be centered any more than it already is. However, we *can* move the voting arrows over by one pixel to the right and make them actually centered with the text in between them.

What I currently use in my custom CSS:

```css
.votecell .vote a { background-position-x: 1px !important }
```

Obviously it would be simpler to edit the original `background-position` rules in the actual stylesheet. Anyways, that rule produces the following:

[image: Vote count with arrows re-aligned]

**Note:** The default font is somewhat misleading due to the way the browser renders it (the character gets rendered in an odd-numbered pixel amount, so it *appears* to need another one pixel shift). So, I used the Courier New font to emphasize that only one pixel to the right is needed to align correctly with the text. Silly font rendering.