# It's time for a redesign of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, design

I think that the Stack Overflow website should be redesigned. Let's compare,

Stack Overflow

http://d.pr/i/797R+

Then, we look at another design

User Experience

http://d.pr/i/m0cL+

While I understand UX is UX, why can't we take these type of designs and fit them for Stack Overflow? No offense, but it looks kinda ugly. I think it's time to adapt to the new modern and clean designs the majority of the web is starting to adapt. I'd love thoughts on why you would/wouldn't love this, and a response from Stack Exchange would be nice.

Comment: A while == 1 month?

Comment: [We're pretty sensitive about changes when it comes to CSS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158762/200500)

Comment: What _modern and clean standards_? Please use the word _standard_ with caution. Perhaps you mean something like _emerging conventions_ or _trends_?

Comment: Ok, very sensitive I see. However, are you going to support the "ugly" version. It just does not have enough "new" in it. I should stop putting "air quotes :)" in my "sentences"

Comment: Let me just leave this here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: Possible duplicate, however nobody has given any feedback on both, and simply disagreed. I'd like a reason...

Comment: @IanCarroll Then a bounty on the duplicate might possibly make sense? You'll need some rep for that first though.

Comment: Yeah, still new here. :\

Comment: [Redesigns break my workflow](http://xkcd.com/1172/).

Comment: @Dennis :D Well, that is a very rare case.

Comment: @animuson I browsed around and looked for answers, didn't sign up.

Comment: *::Compares::* *::Compares again, in case he missed something::* Er...so what exactly is it that you prefer on UX? The colors of some of the features on the page? The round corners? I mean, be specific, man! The use of space is essentially the same, so you're going to have to identify what makes one "modern" and "clean" and the other "ugly" because it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: I like the rounded text, the modern look of the vote up and down buttons, mostly the "modern" stuff.

Comment: The images you linked to no longer exist. Can you re-upload them in the post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm certainly no design aficionado, but I think one of the big benefits that Stack Overflow brought to the web was a completely new design relative to the forum/help sites that pre-existed it.  It was a design based on functionality and has served it very well.  It is a design that all the other Stack Exchange sites are based on.

So I guess I'd want much more concrete examples of what should be changed.

Comment: Well put! I completely agree.

Answer (score 15):

Because Stack Exchange's designer Jin is a very [peaceful fellow who enjoys his bacon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMIex.gif), the thought of having to wage epic battle with all of the pitchfork-toting Stack Overflow users who let forth their war-eeeeeek every time their cheese is moved weighs heavily on his mind.

This gives him great pause, and consequently he makes tweaks to the design of the triology very, very slowly in an effort to stem the tide of violence. Join him in his quest of patience, and keep hope - there will be a shinier future, someday.

Comment: A shinier future? Not on our watch.

Comment: @Asad: A shinier watch may be in your future, however.

Comment: This may not be the beat poetry of random♦, but it is certainly one of the most well-phrased posts I've seen on Meta. It oscillates admirably.