# Who stole the tag shadows?

Tags: discussion, tags, design

Just an hour ago, they were still there! Now, it seems, somebody took 'em far away. Luckily, [a buddy of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) had a unicorn-powered time machine in the backyard, so I can deliver proof of the evil deeds:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

On a personal note, I liked those shadows. Good buddies. Can haz back?

Comment: Funny thing: Mixed up on meta. See this questions' tags.

Comment: [GOTTA SAVE THE PIXELS!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158762/whats-up-with-the-new-css/158763#158763)

Comment: @juergend: The meta tags are also shadow-less for me.

Comment: They just trimmed the tags' height.

Comment: Yay! My question is on your screenshot :D

Comment: Personally, I didn't mind losing the Windows 3.1 look.

Answer (score 13):

We recently learned that the Russians have developed ground-breaking *shadowless tag* technology. As I'm sure you can imagine, the advantage this gives them could be catastrophic to our aims at world domination.

Our intrepid designer has worked *day and night*  to close this *shadow gap*. We're not *quite* there yet, but it can only be a matter of time...

Comment: So I guess you knew better than to call it a [performance issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158762/whats-up-with-the-new-css/158763#comment459391_158763) - especially in front of me. :)

Comment: We're back in NYC now, less need to scrimp on pixels... Unless there's a STRATEGIC MILITARY ADVANTAGE to doing so

Comment: btw, may we ask what you are on right now? :P [Since we're talking about you in the lounge atm.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7860779#7860779) :)

Comment: Kraft Macaroni & Cheese - the genuine original!

Comment: Wait, I'm confused...The buttons became *more* 3D, but the tags went in the opposite direction? What the what? I guess I'll trust in Jin's grander vision...for now. :P

Comment: They look much better than before. +1

Comment: Someone has killed Peter Pan once and for all

Comment: I have to say the new hover effect looks really odd on the red-status-tags of Meta (white text on light grey background). Can the status tags get a different background color on hover?

Comment: @animuson that's a bug. I've already pushed a fix to dev.

Comment: The button kinda blend into the background, which makes it harder to see it...

Comment: Worrying about the Russians is so 1985. The *Chinese* are where it's at these days!