# Please unbold the reputation next to a user's card

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, user-card

[image] [image]

This looks like it has recently changed (could just be me) but I think it used to look like this:

[image]

Can it be changed back - bold seems quite jarring? I can see that it makes it stand out but I do prefer the old style.

Comment: This has happened network-wide, not just on beta sites.

Comment: @bluefeet Intentionally - as in new design? Or bad css released?

Comment: This was an intentional change to have the rep be a bit more visible when displayed next to the badge totals.

Comment: @bluefeet okay, changed to feature-request.

Comment: It also used to be quite a bit lighter - the font weight wasn't the only thing that changed.

Comment: ========= Enough comments, this is a feature request, upvote for change back ==========

Comment: We have beefier servers and fatter pipes - **[of course we gotta have more bold!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158762/whats-up-with-the-new-css/158763#158763)**

Comment: @Shog9 I think you had a different font back then.  Now it's kinda hard to read bold numbers like "806" when there's only a pixel of space between them.

Comment: @Shog9 so every 3 years you toggle boldness?

Comment: I *think* the color and the boldness was the same as the color and the boldness of the reputation (still) shown for the users in the questions tabs.

Comment: @Tim The boldness has been dimmed.

Comment: @bluefeet that looks status completed to me :) much less jarring - thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this is still bold however "dimmed" by making the color lighter:

> [image]

All in all, fair compromise in my opinion.

Comment: **It's become bold again! (on Stack Overflow)**

Comment: @FarhanAnam it's bold here too, but in SO the color is darker indeed. Not black though, so still not terrible.

Comment: 6-8 of course, @Far. BTW you can ask me anything in the chat, I've got a room there. :-)